# how do I change URL on page load javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to change url of the page by using

```
<body onload="location.replace('new url')">
```

but I want this to be back to my old URL on click un checking of a check box.
so suppose i have a checkbox as follows:

```
<input type="checckbox" checked>
```

as soon i uncheck it the page should go to the old url

Comment: Add a click event to the checkbox that checks for checked and if so, execute: `location = document.referer;`

Comment: As an aside, why are you using a checkbox instead of an `a` anchor or some other navigation button? Checkboxes (which you misspelled in your example, by the way) are semantically not navigation elements.

Answer (score 1):

use `window.location.href` instead.

```
<body onload="window.location.href = 'https://google.com'">
```